# Yii2 + Nginx(proxy) + Apache(back)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx, proxy

I'm learning NGINX and I need to set a frontend webserver with NGINX and a backend webserver with Apache using `.htaccess`

This is the content of `/etc/nginx/sites-available/my_test5.loc`

```
server {
  charset utf-8;
  client_max_body_size 128M;

  listen 80;

  server_name my_test5.loc;
  root        /var/www/my_test5.loc/web;
  #root /var/www/my_test5.loc;
  index       index.php;


  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
  }

  # deny accessing php files for the /assets directory
  location ~ ^/assets/.*\.php$ {
    deny all;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {    
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
  }

  location ~* /\. {
    #  deny all;
    allow all;
  }
}
```

This is the content of `/etc/apache2/sites-available/my_test5.loc.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
  <Directory /var/www/my_test5.loc/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All 
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all 
  </Directory>
  ServerAdmin admin@my_test5.loc
  ServerName my_test5.loc
  ServerAlias www.my_test5.loc
  DocumentRoot /var/www/my_test5.loc/web/
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Now all I have working is the main page. If I try to navigate to site/about for example I can't. What have I done wrong and how to use these 2 web servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your setup is only pointing correctly into `index.php` because of your `location / {}` directive, try editing your to be more permissive about your Apache access changing this block to pass through it and adding specific block to other kind of files, like assets.

```
location / {
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}

location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2)$ {
  try_files $uri $uri/
}
```

This way NGINX serves your static files and Apache serves everything else.

Comment: thanks, but it`s doesen`t help. I change my sever code part as you say, and still can ork only with site/index. Maybe something wrong with apache conf?

Comment: Make the failing request and copy/paste both NGINX and Apache logs from that request into your question so that it can be debuggable.

Comment: sorry Mr. ErvalhouS. My question is done and i wrote about it in comment higher. I don't know how to set final answer(

Comment: Your configuration seems fine. I can't debug your problem based only in the configuration posted on the question. You need to disclose more information so that your problem becomes clearer to me. The way to do it is editing your question attaching your logs output into it.

Comment: ErvalhouS my question is done. I just don't know how to close the question and give your comment status "Final version" or something like that, thanks))

Comment: Check  [How to update and accept answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251399/3399504)

Answer (score -2):

For Nginx work

1. use .htaccess for apache
2. siteName.conf apache must be
3. siteName conf must be in nginx sites-available and sites-enable
4. be sure that you send request from 80 port to 8080(as in my case) and Apache are listening  it